# Final rendering add reflection on materials

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

When final rendering add reflection on materials. But I don't know how to delete. I'd like to delete reflection on materials.
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Princepled node set Specular to 0

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have lights in the scene that are hidden in the viewport. Go to the outliner, enable the render visibillity buttons by opening the filter menu in the top right and check if any of the disabled lights are enabled in the render.

Comment: Thank you so much.